# Avoid sql injection on checkbox in gridview

Tags: sql-injection

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkIsHidden" runat="server" Enabled="false" 
    Checked='<%# Convert.IsDBNull(Eval("Is_Hidden")) ? false : Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Is_Hidden")) %>' 
/>
```

Above code, Security program scan and alert that "Blind SQL Injection", I'm so confuse

1. Why it has SQL injection?
2. How to fix to avoid sql injection?

Comment: Are you want any detail?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, even if your Web application does not return error messages, it may still be susceptible to blind SQL injection attacks. However, you can protect your organization's applications against attacks with the following best practices:

1. Create a policy that enforces secure coding practices to ensure vulnerability detection and assessments are performed during any application development or deployment.
2. Have your developers identify where data enters or exits the application and ensure that validation occurs for every part of the HTTP request before letting it anywhere near scripts, data access routines and SQL queries. This will prevent user-supplied data from being able to modify the syntax of SQL statements.
3. Completely isolate your Web applications from SQL using stored procedures, which the application should execute using a safe interface, such as JDBC's CallableStatement or ADO's Command Object. If SQL statements must be generated on the fly, use PreparedStatements, as both PreparedStatements and stored procedures compile the SQL statement before the user input is added, making it impossible for user input to modify the actual SQL statement.
4. Consider using a vulnerability assessment tool to automate the discovery of SQL injection and other security vulnerabilities.
5. Develop an incident response plan. Having a detailed and well-rehearsed plan will help you handle any attack that occurs in an orderly and effective manner, and minimize the impact to your organization.